Can a person with mental disorder(s) ask questions here?
The site itself says it is a place for teachers, students, and enthusiasts in psychology. But can people with mental disorders also ask questions here?
Maybe someone is suffering from OCD and/or Schizofrenia, who is shy to go visit a doctor and wants to get advices for free online.

Personal medical/psychological/psychiatric advice and self-help is strictly not allowed here.
We do not verify the credentials of anyone posting; if someone posts expecting medical advice, they are getting an answers from some unknown person on the internet, yet it might appear to them they are hearing from a professional. This is dangerous.
Worse, there are ethical issues with providing medical advice without fully examining patients. Anyone who is qualified and provides an answer is likely breaking ethical standards in their field to do so.
This site is not and cannot be a substitute for professional help.
See also:
Why was my self-help question closed as off-topic?
